# Behavior of constructors when copy constructor is defined by user

Tags: c++

Iam trying to understand copy constructors please understand me how it works.

**Case 1**

```
class fruit{
    public: int i;
            fruit(int j){
               i = j;
            }
};

int main(){
   fruit f1 = fruit(2); // works fine when no user defined copy constructor
   return 0;
}
```

**Case 2**

```
class fruit{
    public: int i;
            fruit(fruit &f){
               i = f.i + 1;
            }
            fruit(int j){
               i = j;
            }
};

int main(){
   fruit f1 = fruit(2); // error no matching call fruit::fruit(fruit) why?
   return 0;
}
```

**Case 3**

```
class fruit{
    public: int i;
            fruit(){
               i = 0;
            }
};

int main(){
   fruit f2;
   fruit f1 = fruit(f2); // works fine when no user defined copy constructor
   return 0;
}
```

**Case 4**

```
class fruit{
    public: int i;
            fruit(){
               i = 0;
            }
            fruit(fruit &f){
              i = f.i + 1;
            }
};

int main(){
   fruit f2;
   fruit f1 = fruit(f2); // error no matching call fruit::fruit(fruit)
   return 0;
}
Technically 'fruit(f2)' must be valid because 
f2 can be passed by reference to fruit(fruit &f). right? but why error?
```

Why do I get error in `Case 2` and `Case 4`? is this because I created user defined copy constructor? If the reason is user defined copy constructor, even compiler provides default copy constructors. like `fruit(fruit &)` internally So even then copy constructors are available to program provided by compiler. Why it does not raise error in `Case 1` and `Case 3`

I understand all constructors are blocked with `=` when user defines copy constructor. `=` can invoke only copy constructor. but there must be one copy constructor to a class may be by user or by compiler. If it is provided by compiler then also it must raise error. but it does not do why?

Comment: `fruit(fruit&)` isn't a copy constructor, just a regular constructor that requires an l-value `fruit` reference. `fruit(fruit const&)` is a copy constructor, and `fruit(fruit&&)` is a move constructor, which would be called (if provided) given your examples. This is because you're constructing temporaries, which are not l-values, and so can't be bound to l-value references (`&`), but can be bound to r-value references (`&&`).

Comment: @Cameron: Yes, that is a copy constructor. Not as generally useful as one which takes a const reference, but a copy constructor just the same.

Comment: @Cameron: Unfortunately, it _is_ a copy constructor. I don't think it should be, but `[C++11: 12.8/2]` disagrees.

Comment: @Benjamin, Lightness: Hey cool, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem specifically related to copy constructors; non-`const` lvalues references cannot bind to temporaries.

The following code would have compiled:

```
fruit f1;
fruit f2(f1);
```

because `f1` is not a temporary when you pass it in.

Still, you want temporaries to work, so write your copy constructor like this:

```
fruit(const fruit& f) {
   i = f.i + 1;
}
```

Your cases 1 and 3 succeed because the compiler is able to generate its own "default" copy constructor *having seen that you did not provide one*, which — unlike you — it does correctly. :-)

Comment: Could you explain why does case 2 fail? Iam passing integer why would compiler check for fruit(fruit) ?

Comment: @user3205479: You're passing an integer into `fruit(int)`, which works fine.... but then you copy the resulting temporary object into `f1` and that fails for the same reason as the other cases. If you'd just written `fruit f1(2);` then it would have worked, because that doesn't involve copying any fruit.

Comment: It may be temporary but why would it check for fruit(fruit) when there is a constructor fruit(int a)?

Comment: @user3205479: I just explained that. `fruit(int a)` is used first, to create that temporary. _Then_ you are trying to copy the result into `f1` for initialisation. That requires a copy constructor. You did not write `fruit f1(2)`; you wrote `fruit f1 = fruit(2);`.

Comment: @user3205479 `fruit x = fruit(2)` does `fruit(2)` (creates a temporary fruit) then does `fruit x=` which copies that temporary fruit into `x`.  This construction is often elided (skipped), but it must be legal before it is skipped.  There is no way to turn the `fruit(2)` into `fruit x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fruit f1 = fruit(f2);
```

For fruit(f2) , temporary would be created which cannot be bind to non-const reference. You have to use follwoing copy constrcutor for this to work:-

```
fruit(const fruit& f)
```

Comment: Could you explain why does case 2 fail? Iam passing integer why would compiler check for fruit(fruit)

Comment: On the same line fruit(2) would result in temporary being created out of default constructor...